# Huey Monitor - Error occurred sending signal "executing" - database kills the connection

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-signals, python-huey

In a Django 4.1 project I have `huey` (2.4.5) with `django-huey` (1.1.1) and `django-huey-monitor` (0.7.1) set up. Redis broker.
5 queues, including default, and are run in docker containers:

```
PYTHONBUFFERED=1 python manage.py djangohuey --queue queue_name --no-periodic --force-color
```

The monitor is initialised as such in `tasks/__init__.py`:

```
for queue_name in settings.DJANGO_HUEY["queues"].keys():
    signal(queue=queue_name)(store_signals)
    on_startup(queue=queue_name)(startup_handler)
```

Since adding `django-huey-monitor` Sentry has started to catch exceptions in `@db_task` tasks

```
Error occurred sending signal "executing"

OperationalError
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

Now, I've experienced something like that in the past (5+ years ago) and usually, it helped to add `connection.close()` at the end of the task imported from `django.db` thous `@db_task` should do it anyway.
Now everything was running smoothly, `@db_task` and all, until I added signal monitoring. I tested one `@db_task` that should be closing the connection anyway, added the `connection.close()` - that one seems to go silent but another one started acting up.

I'd like to solve it globally and have run out of ideas.

Are the signals misconfigured?